# mrender for 2 data variables not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, datatables

I want to use mrender for 2 data variables . my ajax data source is like:

```
{"campaigns":{"campDetails":[{"campaign_id":"1012","campaign_name":"RP - Axe Sample (Submit)","campaign_desc":"Get your FREE sample of Axe Deodorant!","cost":"$0.00","epc":"$0.14","cr":"8.01","payout":"$1.25","url":"http:\/\/www.adworkmedia.com\/go.php?camp=1012&pub=24043&sid=","image":"http:\/\/www.adworkmedia.com\/image.php?pub=24043&id=3061&sid=","categories":"Email & Zip Submits, Survey \/ Freebie \/ Sweepstakes","incent":"Incent,No Points,No Cash","countries":"US","teaseText":"Get a Sample of Axe Deodorant! Details Apply!","teaseDesc":"Get a Sample of Axe Deodorant with your participation!","conversion_point":"E-mail Submit","device_type":"All Devices (Mobile Friendly)"},{},{}....]}}
```

so I have used sAjaxDataProp for rendering the data in the form of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
         "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
        "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost/survey/justearn/index/dist/downloadfile/php/",
        "processing": true,
        "sAjaxDataProp": "campaigns.campDetails",
         "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "campaign_name" },
            {
    "mData": "url",
    "mRender": function(data, type, val) {
        switch (type) {
            case 'display':
                return '<a href="/data/' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
                break;
            // optionally, add case statements for 'sort', 'filter', and 'type'
            default:
                return data.bar;
                break;
        }
    }
},
            { "mData": "cr" }



        ]
    } );
} );

}
```

I am able to get campaign_name and cr columns while processing but the 2nd columns seems to have an error, thats because i want to use 2 mData for the same mRender function

I tried using

```
 {"mData": "foo",
     "mData2": "bar",
     "mRender": function(data, data2){
          return '<a href="/data/' + data + '">bar</a>'; //
      }
    }
```

Since I am new to array could you help me solve the 2nd column so I may be able to mRender it,you can use the ajax source i posted above, I want the two  mData variables for the second column  as "url" and "campign_desc" using mRender from the ajax data source above.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug your code using Firebug you'd be able to see that `val` contains the row data, so displaying it if the way you want is simply a case of:

```
{
   'mRender': function (data, type, val) {
            return <a href="/data/' + val[0] + '">' + val[1] + '</a>';
    }
}
```